# Conditional rendering react issue

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have made a [code sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/93464x27w4) to be clearer.

I want to use conditional rendering in a certain part of my render method but I am struggling to achieve this.

I am struggling to render conditionally at this point `group.code === "TEST" && group.markets.length == 3 ?`

I get the following error

> Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected , (252:15)

My code is below:

```
class Example extends Component {    
  render() {        
    return (          
      <div className="Container">    
        {
          groups.map(group => {    
          return (    
            <div key={group.id}>    
              {
                groups.length > 1 &&
                <h4 className="GroupHeader">{group.label}</h4>
              }    
              {
                group.code === "TEST" && group.markets.length == 3 ? 
                (
                  <div>
                    <p>UPDATING GROUP...</p>
                  </div>
                ) : (    
                    {
                      group.map(g => {    
                        const groupObj = {
                          id: g.g_id
                        };    
                        return (
                          <Group 
                            key={groupObj.id}
                            {...groupObj}
                          />
                        );    
                      })
                    }    
                )    
              }        
            </div>
          )
        })            
      }    
      </div>
    );
  }    
}
```

Comment: wrap you map content in the else condition within a div `group.code === "TEST" && group.markets.length == 3 ? 
                (
                  <div>
                    <p>UPDATING GROUP...</p>
                  </div>
                ) : (

                    <div>{ group.map()` and it should work provided you export the component properly and have Component imported from React

Comment: @ShubhamKhatribeautiful! want to add it as an answer with an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you map content in the else condition within a `div` since the returned value needs to a single Element

```
class Example extends Component {    
  render() {        
    return (          
      <div className="Container">    
        {
          groups.map(group => {    
          return (    
            <div key={group.id}>    
              {
                groups.length > 1 &&
                <h4 className="GroupHeader">{group.label}</h4>
              }    
              {
                group.code === "TEST" && group.markets.length == 3 ? 
                (
                  <div>
                    <p>UPDATING GROUP...</p>
                  </div>
                ) : (    
                    <div>{
                      group.map(g => {    
                        const groupObj = {
                          id: g.g_id
                        };    
                        return (
                          <Group 
                            key={groupObj.id}
                            {...groupObj}
                          />
                        );    
                      })
                    }</div>
                )    
              }        
            </div>
          )
        })            
      }    
      </div>
    );
  }    
}
```